# Why are these points destroyed three times?

Tags: c++, destroy

Ｈere is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class Point {
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
        Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
        ~Point() {
            printf("Point destroyed: (%d, %d)\n", x, y);
        }
};

class Square {
    private:
        Point upperleft;
        Point lowerright;
    public:
        Square(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) : upperleft(x1, y1), lowerright(x2, y2) {}
        Square(Point p1, Point p2) : upperleft(p1), lowerright(p2) {}
        ~Square() {
            printf("Square destroyed.\n");
        }
};

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    Point p1(1, 2);
    Point p2(3, 4);
    Square s1(p1, p2);
    return 0;
}
```

After compile (`g++ x.cpp`) and run, I got the following results:

```
Point destroyed: (1, 2)
Point destroyed: (3, 4)
Square destroyed.
Point destroyed: (3, 4)
Point destroyed: (1, 2)
Point destroyed: (3, 4)
Point destroyed: (1, 2)
```

I expect each Point to be destroyed twice, but they are destroyed three times instead. Why?

Comment: What compiler and what options?

Comment: p1 and p2 will be destroyed, as will the copies made when passing them to the `Square` constructor and then the second pair of copies made when constructing your data members from those copies.

Comment: How to pass them without constructing new ones? By reference?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik you would pass them as `Point const&`, although in this case I would just pass them by value because `Point` is a very small class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because

```
Square(Point p1, Point p2)
```

takes arguments passed by value which creates a copy of the parameters you pass to it. So you have

1. The original parameters
2. The copies passed to the `Square` constructor
3. The member variables of the instance of `Square` you create

3 instances.

Comment: So in total there are two copies, why are they destroyed three times?

Comment: @qed When you pass parameters **by value** to a function, temporary copies are made of the original arguments.

Comment: @qed Three copies: The original in the `main` function, the copy made by passing by value to the constructor, and the `Square` member variable.

Answer (score 2):

you copy them into the constructor

try `Square(const Point& p1,const  Point& p2) : upperleft(p1), lowerright(p2) {}`

results in

```
Square destroyed.
Point destroyed: (3, 4)
Point destroyed: (1, 2)
Point destroyed: (3, 4)
Point destroyed: (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This constructor

```
Square(Point p1, Point p2) : upperleft(p1), lowerright(p2) {}
```

accepts objects of type Point by value. So these temporary objects that created as parameters of the constructor are also deleted.

You could define the constructor the following way

```
Square( const Point &p1, const Point &p2) : upperleft(p1), lowerright(p2) {}
```

to escape creating temporary objects during its call.

It is interesting to see the order in which destructors are called

```
Point destroyed: (1, 2)
Point destroyed: (3, 4)
Square destroyed.
Point destroyed: (3, 4)
Point destroyed: (1, 2)
Point destroyed: (3, 4)
Point destroyed: (1, 2)
```

These two lines

```
Point destroyed: (1, 2)
Point destroyed: (3, 4)
```

mean that the compiler at first created the second argument Point(3, 4) and then the first argument Point( 1, 2 ). They are deleted in the reverse order.

These two lines

```
Point destroyed: (3, 4)
Point destroyed: (1, 2)
```

mean that at first data member upperleft was created because it declared before lowerright and then lowerright was created. Again they are deleted in the reverse order.

And at last these two lines

```
Point destroyed: (3, 4)
Point destroyed: (1, 2)
```

mean that at first Point( 1, 2 ) was created because it is defined before Point( 3, 4 ) in main and then Point( 3, 4 ) was created. They are deleted in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Destroy twice, using references:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class Point {
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
        Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
        ~Point() {
            printf("Point destroyed: (%d, %d)\n", x, y);
        }
};

class Square {
    private:
        Point upperleft;
        Point lowerright;
    public:
        Square(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) : upperleft(x1, y1), lowerright(x2, y2) {}
        Square(Point& p1, Point& p2) : upperleft(p1), lowerright(p2) {}
        ~Square() {
            printf("Square destroyed.\n");
        }
};

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    Point p1(1, 2);
    Point p2(3, 4);
    Square s1(p1, p2);
    return 0;
}
```

Destroy once, using pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class Point {
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
        Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
        ~Point() {
            printf("Point destroyed: (%d, %d)\n", x, y);
        }
};

class Square {
    private:
        Point* upperleft;
        Point* lowerright;
    public:
        Square(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            Point* ul = new Point(x1, y1);
            Point* lr = new Point(x2, y2);
            upperleft = ul;
            lowerright = lr;
        }
        Square(Point* p1, Point* p2) : upperleft(p1), lowerright(p2) {}
        ~Square() {
            printf("Square destroyed.\n");
        }
};

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    Point p1(1, 2);
    Point p2(3, 4);
    Square s1(&p1, &p2);
    return 0;
}
```